# After fork(), how to keep running execve() in for() loop?

Tags: c++, linux, loops, fork, execve

Here is an example, ignorning the error checking:

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(0 == pid)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            char* const args[] = { "/bin/ls", nullptr };
            execve("/bin/ls", args, nullptr);
        }
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        wait(nullptr);
    }
}
```

If exec() after fork(), as far as I know, the linux will not copy but cover original system.

If I want to keep running execve() in for() loop like this, what should I do ?

Comment: Call `fork` ***in*** the loop?

Comment: What do you mean about "keep running execve in for loop"? Do you want to run multiple `/bin/ls`?

Comment: If you want to execute `ls` 5 times, you need to call `fork` 5 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between fork and exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653340/differences-between-fork-and-exec)

Comment: Other duplicate questions: [Multiple `execlp` not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188115/multiple-execlp-not-working), [Why does `execv` exit a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27773445/why-does-execv-exit-a-function), [Difference between `system` and `exec` in Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697440/difference-between-system-and-exec-in-linux)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` (all of the different forms) *will* replace your current executable with the one given to `exec`, so NOTHING you do within the forked code will matter. You need to either do a loop around `fork`, or convince the author of the other program to run the loop for you.